# Set connection pool size for DBCP datasource in iBatis

Tags: connection-pooling, mybatis, ibatis, apache-commons-dbcp

How can one set the connection pool size for a DBCP datasource? Also, is the default datasource pooled?

I tried to set `maxTotal` (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html), but it returns an invalid property error.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
  <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="false"/>
  <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
  <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
  <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>     
  <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000"/>
  <property name="maxTotal" value="1"/>     
</bean>


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class pat
h resource [META-INF/spring/base-gateway.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.be
ans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxTotal' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: B
ean property 'maxTotal' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the
 return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.jav
a:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFac
tory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationCo
ntext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at sf.av.core.gateway.GenericGateway.main(GenericGateway.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxTotal' of bean class [org.apache
.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'maxTotal' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the param
eter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1024)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a mismatch between the version of the DBCP jar you are using and the configuration documentation, [for example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/):

> Users should also be aware that some configuration options (e.g. maxActive to maxTotal) have been renamed to align them with the new names used by Commons Pool 2.

Does the `BasicDataSource` class from the jar you are using have the `maxTotal` setter on it or not?

Comment: Is the default datasource pooled?

Comment: @user640378: The default datasource, that of iBatis? iBatis/myBatis has [three supported datasources out of the box](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html): UNPOOLED, POOLED and JNDI. If you are uisng iBatis with spring and you give iBatis a datasource bean then that will dictate if the datasource is pooled or not. You are using a org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource which is pooled.